# Nginx : the rule( location = / ) in server context do not work

Tags: linux, nginx, web

```
server
{
    server_name www.vanging.com;
    root /web/sites/vanging.com/;

    include modules/general.conf;
    include modules/ssl.conf;

    ssl_certificate certs/vanging.com/www/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key certs/vanging.com/www/cert.key;

    error_log /web/sites/vanging.com/logs/www/error.log debug;
    access_log /web/sites/vanging.com/logs/www/access.log;

    location = /
    {
        root /web/sites/vanging.com/www;
    }

}

---------------------------
in modules/general.conf:

listen  80;
index   index.html;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * ;

---------------------------
in modles/ssl.conf:
listen                      443 http2;
ssl                         on;

# Perfect_Forward_Security,Diffie-Hellman
ssl_dhparam                 dhparam.pem;

ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout         5m;
ssl_ciphers                 ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:DES-CBC3-SHA;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_protocols               TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;

# http-->https
if ($server_port = 80)
{
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

if ($scheme = http)
{
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

error_page 497 https://$server_name$request_uri;

add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload";
```

In the config above,I want to put the homepage of my site in the www dir of the document root,but the rule location = / just have no any effect to the incoming request with the url https://www.vanging.com.

Anyone can help ?

Thanks !

Comment: How do you know? Could you post results from dev console, like firebug?

Comment: error.log->2017/05/22 22:13:35 [error] 12353#12353: *57 open() "/web/sites/vanging.com/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.140.11.160, server: www.vanging.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.vanging.com"
2017/05/22 22:13:36 [error] 12353#12353: *57 open() "/web/sites/vanging.com/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.140.11.160, server: www.vanging.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.vanging.com"

Comment: In general, you don't need `location`, just `root` should suffice.

Comment: Btw, you already have `root` and it seems conflicting with the one in `location`.

Comment: Um,Maybe.But I want to put the files(like html,css js) related to homepage in a single dir so it get's easier to manage

Comment: The root in location block won't override the root in the server block ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144846/discussion-between-twesix-and-igor).

Comment: You should use `location /` and not `location = /`. The second version only matches the URI `/` and nothing else. So `/index.html` is not matched, which is why it is using the other `root` value.

Comment: But,when I access https://www.vanging.com the path should be / ,not /index.html.

Comment: I commented the root config in server block the error log is -> 2017/05/22 22:33:12 [error] 12386#12386: *70 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 62.210.181.15, server: www.vanging.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.vanging.com"
This means it just didn't go through the location = / rule?

Comment: And the error status is 404

Answer (score 0):

Finally from other place I found the reason behind this:Index directive works via internal redirect.The request do matches the rule location = / but it will be internal redirected to /index.html so a 404 occurs.

To solve this use try_files directive indtead and it won't cause internal redirect.

I am glad to get your help and I hope this can help those who also get confused by this question.

Thank you,everyone !